# Rails - access foreign_key of belongs_to association in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, simple-form

**Architecture:**
I have two Models: Port and App

- An App belongs to a port
- In the App the relation is defined like following:
  `belongs_to :port,
           class_name: 'Port',
           foreign_key: :port_id,
           required: true`
- A Port has a number and obviously an id (no, id and number aren't equal)

**What I need:**
The Port are already existing in a DB. In the create-form from the app I have list with all available ports: `<%= f.association :port, collection: Port.available_ports, include_blank: false %>`.
With this approach, the value of a select Item is equal to the number of the port. But what I need is, that the value isn't the number but the id of the port.

**What I tried:**
I tried to solve my problem by adding following to the f.association: `value_method: Port.available_ports`. But that didn't work: `no implicit conversion of Array into String`.

**My Question:**
Am I on the right track or should I approach my problem in a different way? If so, what would you recommend me to do?

**EDIT:**
    AppController

```
class JBossAppsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :load_app,
                only: %i[ show destroy ]

  def index
    @apps = JBossApp.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @app = JBossApp.new
  end

  def create
    @app = JBossApp.new(app_params)
    if @app.save!
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'j_boss_apps/new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  protected
  def load_app
    @app = JBossApp.find_by(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def app_params
    params.require(:j_boss_app).permit(
        params.require(:j_boss_app).permit(
            :id, :group_id, :port_id, :environment, :status, :fault_count, :request_count, :response_count
        )
    )
  end

end
```

Port

```
class Port < ApplicationRecord


# Helper
  def self.available_ports
    unavailable_ports = Port.order(number: :asc).pluck(:number)
    first_port = 8080
    last_port = 65080
    step = 100
    all_ports = (first_port..last_port).step(step).collect { |n| n }
    all_ports - unavailable_ports
  end

# Relations
  has_many :apps,
           class_name: 'JBossApp',
           foreign_key: :port_id,
           dependent: :destroy

  has_one :int_app, ->{
    where(port_id: id, environment: :int)
  }

  has_one :tst_app, ->{
    where(port_id: id, environment: :tst)
  }

  has_one :prd_app, ->{
    where(port_id: id, environment: :prd)
  }

  has_one :dmz_tst_app, ->{
    where(port_id: id, environment: :dmz_tst)
  }

  has_one :dmz_prd_app, ->{
    where(port_id: id, environment: :dmz_prd)
  }

# Validations
  validates :number,
            numericality: {
                greater_than: 0,
                only_integer: true
            },
            presence: true

end
```

Comment: <%= f.collection_select :port_id, Port.available_ports, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a port"}, {class: "form-control"} %>

See the API docs for 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: @Dnyanarthlonkar It's number, not name. And if i change it follwoing error appears: `undefined method number for 8080:Fixnum
Did you mean?  numerator`

Comment: you can use the attribute you want to show in select list instead of name ie  replace your attritube that you want to display  in place of name

Comment: <%= f.collection_select :port_id, Port.all, :id, :your_attribute_to_display, {prompt: "Select a port"}, {class: "form-control"} %>

Comment: can u please paste your apps controller and port model.

Comment: @Dnyanarthlonkar I added both and will try your other answer.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to populate the list of available ports which have yet not been added to ports table?

Comment: @ManojMonga no, I want to list all the available ports that are provided by the method "available_ports" but the actual value that gets processed (that isn't visible for the user) should be the id of the port and not the number.

Comment: **Port.order(number: :asc).pluck(:number)** in available_ports method will get all the port numbers from Ports table, right? Then you are trying to find the available ports between 8080 and 65080 which are not in the **unavailable_ports** array (In other words, they do not exist in the Ports table).

If they don't even exist, how would you get their ID?

Comment: Please confirm if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: @ManojMonga Wrong and right :D. First I get all unavailable ports. Then I create an array with all ports from 8080 to 65080. Then I substract all the ports that are unavailable from the list with all ports from 8080 to 65080. That's how I get the available ports.  If they don't even exist, I can't get the ID. But that means I have to create them and receive the ID at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140073/discussion-between-manoj-monga-and-colin-herzog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding to the Question, you would **EITHER** need insert the Port number entered by the user to the `Ports` table and associate it to the app while saving it **OR** seed all the Ports to `Ports` table beforehand and then find the ports which do not have their corresponding/associated apps. For that you can change your `available_ports` method as follows:

```
def self.available_ports
  Port.includes(:apps).where(apps: {id: nil}).order(ports:{number: :asc})

  # Or similar results can be achieved by the following in Rails 5
  # Port.left_outer_joins(:apps).where(apps: {id: nil}).order(ports:{number: :asc})
end
```

Now you can use your normal form helper method `collection_select` as:

```
<%= f.collection_select :port_id, Port.available_ports, :id, :number, {prompt: "Select a port"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

Please let me know if you need further help with any of the proposed solutions.

Comment: "need insert the Port number entered by the user to the Ports table and associate it to the app while saving it" is correct.

Comment: Wait a minute.. I just got into a discussion with my collegue. He asked me to try your solution. With this one I get an empty list. I changed the function to: `Port.includes(:apps).where(j_boss_apps: {port_id: nil})` to simplify it a bit. But as I said: the list remains empty. What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: Have you add all the Ports into the table? Make sure, you have all the ports between 8080 and 65080 in the table.

Comment: Yes I added all the Ports into the table

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.available_ports
    unavailable_ports = Port.order(number: :asc).pluck(:number)
    first_port = 8080
    last_port = 65080
    step = 100
    all_ports = (first_port..last_port).step(step).collect { |n| n }
    all_ports = all_ports - unavailable_ports
    all_ports = Port.where(number: all_ports)
 end
```

in views

```
<%= f.collection_select :port_id, Port.available_ports, :id, :number, {prompt: "Select a port"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

Comment: @colin Herzog you need to insert available port number into port table, then you will get the list.

Comment: Good Point. But if the Port Number is already in the table, wouldn't it become unavailable port? `unavailable_ports = Port.order(number: :asc).pluck(:number)` :)

Comment: @manoj Yes absolutely right,Then adding  a enum or Boolean flag in port table will be a good solution and then fetch only available ports by adding scope in model.

Comment: Yes, I added a boolean flag to the table and a scope to the model.

Comment: That is also fine but you could also get the available port without adding the flag. As I mentioned in my answer. Anyways, that is more on the personal choice to use any of these :) Also, please update your answer as well, so that it doesn't confuse the others!

Comment: @ManojMonga I'll do that as soon as my colluege approves my work.